# How can I make my images be hidden only inside modal box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a modal box named **sectors**; inside are two sub categories: publication and food.

Both sub categories are attached to `div` which contains an image.

I want to be able to have the image be hidden inside my modal box, but show on screen once the modal box is closed.

I have tried using `display:none` within the `div` but this doesn't seem to solve the problem.

```js
    var content = "";

$('a[href="#ex5"]').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).modal({
    escapeClose: false,
    clickClose: false,
    showClose: false,
  });
  $('#myDiv, #myDivs').addClass('hideme');
  $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
});

$('.yourCheckbox, .yourCheckboxx').change(function() {
  var elemContent = $("#" + $(this).data('target')).html();
  if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
    //$("#" + $(this).data('target')).removeClass('hideme');
    content += elemContent;
  } else {
    //$("#" + $(this).data('target')).addClass('hideme');
    content = content.replace(elemContent, '');
  }

  $("#" + $(this).data('target')).toggleClass('hideme');
});


$('[rel="modal:close"]').on('click', () => {
  $('.btn').siblings().first().html('').append(content);
  content= '';
})
```

```css
.onlyThese {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]+label {
  color: blue
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
  color: red
}


}
input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.hideme {
  display: none;
}
.spaz {
  color: blue;
  margin-left: 40%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Remember to include jQuery :) -->

<!-- jQuery Modal -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />

<p> <a class="btn" href="#ex5">Sectors </a> <span class="spaz"></span> </p>

<div id="ex5" ; class="modal" ; style="background-color:white">

  <div style="float:left;">

    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" id="group1" class="yourCheckbox" data-target="myDiv" checked="checked">
      <label for="group1" class="onlyThese">Publication </label>
    </p>

    <div id="myDiv">
      <img src="https://tse4.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.qKsWIt_Qae6vtWd3-RulIQHaHa&pid=Api&P=0&w=300&h=300.jpg"> </div>
    <p>

      <input type="checkbox" id="group2" class="yourCheckboxx" data-target="myDivs" checked="checked">
      <label for="group2" class="onlyThese">Food </label>
    </p>

    <div id="myDivs">
      <img src="https://tse3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.HcL9FITSR_SWsLMgMFMkYAHaEo&pid=Api&P=0&w=281&h=176.jpg"> </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <p style="float:right">
        <a href="#" rel="modal:close" ; class="onlyThese;"> <b>Apply</b> </a>
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>
```

The expected outcome is as follows:

- User clicks on the modal box named **sectors**
- User clicks on a sub category e.g publication
- the contents of the sub category load up/ are fetched from the div,
  but does not show inside the modal box
- the user clicks apply and the modal box closes where the content
  now shows

Comment: Is there a reason for having semicolons in the HTML (`<div id="ex5"; class="modal"; `, others)? It's not valid HTML, and a little distracting. Also, your CSS has an extra `}` in it. As far as the question goes, move your images (and the `div`s that contain them outside of your modal `div`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to change the way you are creating the model,

You JS should change as follows. It might not be working as what you have expected but you can now make it work as you have got the events with you. Comment further if you need help

```
var content = "";
$('a[href="#ex5"]').click(function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();

  // hide the images
  $('#myDiv,#myDivs').hide();

  // instead of this use the actual div, this will be useful to bind the events 
  $('#ex5').modal({
    escapeClose: false,
    clickClose: false,
    showClose: false,

  })

// bind the before close event
  $('#ex5').on($.modal.BEFORE_CLOSE , function(event, modal) {
  // show the image before modal close
  $('#myDiv,#myDivs').show();
});

});

$('.yourCheckbox, .yourCheckboxx').change(function() {
  if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
    //$("#" + $(this).data('target')).removeClass('hideme');
    content = $("#" + $(this).data('target')).html();
  } else {
    //$("#" + $(this).data('target')).addClass('hideme');
    content = "";
  }

  $("#" + $(this).data('target')).toggleClass('hideme');
});


$('[rel="modal:close"]').on('click', () => {
  $('.btn').siblings().first().html('').append(content);
})
})
```

reference https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-modal#events

Comment: Where would i place this new id?

Comment: @OmegaBlastoise I have modified my answer. #ilovepokemontoo

Comment: Thanks so much for going to such lengths for me, but I am just struggling to wrap my head around where I am placing these new lines of code and what I am renaming my divs/id too. Could you please provide my a snippet of working code using this brilliant examples. Thanks so much.

Comment: The js provided in the answer is a working example. replace your js code with this one. if you need further help we can sort it over the chat provided by stack overflow.

Comment: no worries. Let me know what code has been changed? you can edit the question and requirements.

Comment: The code can now output two images after modal box closes.

Comment: so far, what I have understood is, When the page is loaded, you want those images to be shown as it is. But when you open a popup those images should be hidded. After you close the popup those images should start appearing again? Correct me if i am wrong?

Comment: Initially, both images will be appearing. user clicks selector link. As soon as user clicks selector link, both images disappear -> now user clicks one subcategory -> now when you say relative image to that subcategory is hidded? this statement is confusion. My apologies if i am not understanding your requirement.

Comment: Ok, Let me modify my answer accordingly. This might take a few minutes.

Comment: I have uploaded a file https://gofile.io/?c=5emAOV This HTML file will have the code which may match your requirement. If it doesn't match the let me know.

Comment: does it mean, when the page loads first time, images shouldn't be shown? when user clicks on two check boxes and click apply only then image should be shown?

Comment: Detailed list of the expected outcome everytime the user interacts with the modal box:  1. User clicks on modal box named sectors. 2. User interacts with a sub category (e.g publication) when clicked on it becomes red; **note** when the user has clicked on the sub category and it turns red: it will mean the checkbox linked to it has become checked. 3. when the checkbox is checked  the div containing the image will be shown **key** you were able to make it so the images is not in the modal box but I would like it if the images showed after the user clicks apply. @Sachin Vishwakarma

Comment: This is what I wanted, do u know how to set the check boxes to be unchecked as my questions shows. Basically every time the modal box is opened the sub categories should be blue as it means the check boxes are unchecked; in the example code you gave me you have made the check boxes be checked every time the modal box is opened (the sub categories are red). @Sachin Vishwakarma

Comment: i will modify it.

Comment: https://gofile.io/?c=Pa7m4D this is final. I hope you will be able to make further updates to your requirement. best of luck

Comment: Thanks a bunch; exactly what I wanted. @Sachin Vishwakarma

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197933/discussion-on-answer-by-sachin-vishwakarma-how-can-i-make-my-images-be-hidden-on).